# Why does my Honda Activa handle vibrate a lot at low speed?

Tags: honda, vibration, scooter, activa

I ride a 2014 make Honda Activa. I have maintained it well, give it an engine oil change as per maintenance schedule, and ride it very decently. I do not have any other complaints from the Honda, except the low speed vibrations which become annoying at speeds of 5 to 10 km/h which happens very often in Bangalore traffic.
Can someone please advice on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some analysis on a few auto portals and consulted a few mechanics.Finally found the solution to the problem.

1. **Pre heat your vehicle**:The vibrations occur mostly when the engine is cold and when the engine has not reached the optimum temperature.So pre heat your vehicle for say 2 minutes before you actually ride.
2. **Use kick starter** instead of the self starter for starting your vehicle for the first time in the morning.(This was suggested by a local mechanic, do not know the exact explanation of this yet)

   3. I needed to open the cluth cover and blew some air to remove the dust which was accumulated over the period of time and also cleaned the belt.

Comment: Using the kick starter should make absolutely no difference at all !

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your transmission to allow for higher engine RPM at low speed. This can be achieved through "Variator tuning" and involves using different sized roller weights to alter the ratio/RPM characteristics or your constantly varying transmission.

Look at this article for a more in depth explanation: http://www.pedparts.co.uk/blog/moped-tuning--rollers

It sounds like the setup you have now is causing the engine to operate at an RPM which is lugging slightly and causing excessive vibration.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the oring at the bottom of the fuel adjustment screw in the carb. This thread has more details:

http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/motorbikes/186962-honda-activa-engine-idling-stalling-issue-caused-faulty-o-ring-fitment-carburetor.html